# how to convert pandas dataframe to libsvm format?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, libsvm

I have pandas data frame like below.

```
df
Out[50]: 
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  ...  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97 \
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1 ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
5   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0 ...   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 ...   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   

[8 rows x 100 columns]
```

I have target variable as an array as below.

```
[1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1]
```

How can I map this target variable to a data frame and convert it into lib SVM format?.

```
equi = {0:1, 1:-1, 2:-1,3:1,4:1,5:-1,6:1,7:1}
df["labels"] = df.index.map[(equi)]
d = df[np.setdiff1d(df.columns,['indx','labels'])]
e = df.label
dump_svmlight_file(d,e,'D:/result/smvlight2.dat')er code here
```

ERROR:

```
 File "D:/spyder/april.py", line 54, in <module>
df["labels"] = df.index.map[(equi)]

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

When I use

```
df["labels"] = df.index.list(map[(equi)])
```

ERROR:

```
AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'list'
```

Please help me to solve those errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need convert `index` [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) and then call [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df["labels"] = df.index.to_series().map(equi)
```

Or use [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) of `index`:

```
df["labels"] = df.rename(index=equi).index
```

All together:

For difference of columns pandas has [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
from sklearn.datasets import dump_svmlight_file

equi = {0:1, 1:-1, 2:-1,3:1,4:1,5:-1,6:1,7:1}

df["labels"] = df.rename(index=equi).index
e = df["labels"]
d = df[df.columns.difference(['indx','labels'])]

dump_svmlight_file(d,e,'C:/result/smvlight2.dat')
```

Also it seems `label` column is not necessary:

```
from sklearn.datasets import dump_svmlight_file

equi = {0:1, 1:-1, 2:-1,3:1,4:1,5:-1,6:1,7:1}
e = df.rename(index=equi).index
d = df[df.columns.difference(['indx'])]
dump_svmlight_file(d,e,'C:/result/smvlight2.dat')
```

Comment: But now next error comes in the next line like below.

Comment: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Ok, I hope now it is final version.